# What kind of assembly instruction is this ld1 {v4.16b - v7.16b}, [x10]?

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64, neon

The below assembly instruction is AArch64 NEON / ASIMD assembly code.

```
ld1 {v4.16b - v7.16b}, [x10]
```

and found some related [page](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0802/b/A64-SIMD-Vector-Instructions/LD1--vector--multiple-structures-) about ld1 instruction.
but there are no reference about minus(-) symbol using in ld1 assembly instruction.  What does it mean?

I guess... it means to put continuous data from the address x10 to the 3rd to 7th vector, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct.  `{v4.16b-v7.16b}` is just shorthand for `{v4.16b, v5.16b, v6.16b, v7.16b}`.

So this instruction loads 64 bytes from `[x10]` and stores them into `v4`, `v5`, `v6`, and `v7` without any deinterleaving.

Comment: Reference: page C1-229 of the [Architecture Reference Manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0487/latest) (version H.a), under "SIMD vector register list".